# Has google toughened the restrictions for manifest package name?

Tags: android, android-manifest, google-play

There is an application (already published to the Play Store) that has package name, that doesn't fully conform to the Java naming convention (like `CompanyName.ApplicationName`).

Today, I was unable to publish updated version to the Play Store because the Developer Console complains about bad package name of the uploaded APK. Existing package name only contains letters and does contain a dot, so the only reason for rejecting it that I can think of is package name starting with the upper-case letter. It does match the previously used package name.

Can it be the case? Are there are some recently implemented restrictions for package name?

**edit**

The error I'm getting is

> The package name of your apk (CompanyName.ApplicationName) is invalid. Package
>   names must start with a character and can only contain characters,
>   numbers, underscores and dots. They must have at least one dot, cannot
>   end with a dot, and cannot contain any runs of more than one
>   consecutive dot.

Comment: It's not completely clear what you're asking. Are you trying to change the package name, or is it the same package name which you have previously used for the same app?

Comment: @GrahamBorland It is the same package name that was previously used for that same app. I'm not trying to change it, I'm trying to upload updated application.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had same problem. Upload your apk in the new Developer Console.

Comment: sorry. the new Developer Console

Answer (score 1):

You need 3 parts like org.meredrica.demo in your classpath to be compatible with android guidelines.

also you want to make it all lowercase, since they are case sensitive and capital names like that indicate classes (at least by convention, i'm not sure if its technically enforced)

So if i see something like CompanyName.ApplicationName I expect a class called CompanyName that contains a subclass ApplicationName.

You also might want to run android lint on your project.

Comment: Yes, I know the guidelines - the problem is the application is already published to the Play Store and I was able to update it until today.

Comment: Sounds like you want to contact playstore support. it should not have been possible to upload that in the first place. http://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=136601&rd=1

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem while updating the apk file for an app with a package name of the form `Aaa.Bbb.Ccc.Ddd`, and Leon's solution worked. Though I did not understand it when I first read it.

What he meant is, in Google Play Android Developer Console, click the "Try the new design" button at the top right (which points to play.google.com/apps/publish/v2) to switch the web interface to a new layout. Uploading the apk in the new web UI works for me.